# Why domain controller making connection on lsass.exe

Tags: domain-controller

One of our DC server making auto connection to multiple IP addresses, when i investigated the process, i observed that lsass.exe is making connection, so can anyone help me why the domain controller making auto connection on using process lsass.exe

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Your question doesn't indicate that any research has been done. Have you searched your question online?

Answer (score 1):

The LSASS process is where the majority of the domain controller functionality lives. It does lots of things that involve communicating with other machines. This ranges from RPC to LDAP to Kerberos to TLS.

You would need to inspect the traffic to see what's going on within those connections, but absent any malicious behavior connections in and out of LSASS is not necessarily abnormal.

Comment: Thanks bro, ports used are 49156, 49153, 3268, 49158 ,can you help me with these information

Comment: Those look like dynamic ports for outgoing traffic, what’s the destination port and protocol (tcp/udp)? These tell quite a lot about what kind of traffic this might be. Another good way to get more insight is to run wireshark on the server and capture the packets, then you can see exactly what you’re dealing with.

Comment: I learned from somewhere that DC does scanning like activity using lsass.exe for RPC communication, Is that true ?

Comment: I don't know what scanning means in this case, but there are hundreds of unique RPC calls in normal DC operations.